# Entity framework - add new record where is only Id

Tags: database, entity-framework

I have table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items] 
(
     [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

`Id` is auto increment and I am creating new record like this:

```
var Context = new Entities();
var Item = new Items();
Context.SaveChanges();
```

But in the table there is no new record. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the item into the entity set.

```
using (var dbCtx = new Entities())
{
   var myItem = new Items();
   dbCtx.Items.Add(myItem);
   dbCtx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I get this error:
"An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."

Comment: You are most likely trying to insert a duplicate. Look at the the following SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762923/how-to-avoid-system-data-entity-infrastructure-dbupdateexception

Comment: I updated my answer. You need to declare the item correctly. My original response was specifically related to the fact that you weren't adding the item to the entity set.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Sorry, I know, where is the issue. Thank you.