# How to solve System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

The `INSERT` statement conflicted with the *FOREIGN KEY* constraint `FK_dbo.CinemaShowTime_dbo.Cinema_cinemaId`. The conflict occurred in database "`CinemaModule`", table "`dbo.Cinema`";

I am successfully saving the result of Cinema in DB but when I try to save movie or `CreateCinemasShowTime` it give me error.

I am trying to render multiple models into single view but `DBUPdateException` occurs.

My Controller code

```
        var cinema = new Cinema();
        cinema.Halls = viewModel.Halls;
        cinema.ContactNumber = viewModel.ContactNumber;
        cinema.TicketFee = viewModel.TicketFee;


        var movie = new Movies();
        movie.MovieName = viewModel.MovieName;
        movie.MovieBio = viewModel.MovieBio;
        movie.MoviePosterUrl = viewModel.MoviePosterUrl;



        var cinemaShowtime = new CinemaShowTime();
        cinemaShowtime.ShowDay = viewModel.ShowDay;
        cinemaShowtime.ShowTime = viewModel.ShowTime;

        db.CinemaShowTimes.Add(cinemaShowtime);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

My Model Code

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MovieName { get; set; }//
    public string MoviePosterUrl { get; set; }//
    public string MovieBio { get; set; }

    //collection of CinemaShowTimes for single movie
    public virtual ICollection<CinemaShowTime> CinemaShowTimes { get; set; }

    //single industry for each Movie
    [ForeignKey("IndustriesInstance")]
    public int? IndustryId { get; set; }
    //reference navigation property
    public virtual Industries IndustriesInstance { get; set; }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762923/how-to-avoid-system-data-entity-infrastructure-dbupdateexception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I solved the problem by simply referencing the movie object towards it's join/relational table

```
var movie = new Movies();
movie.MovieName = viewModel.MovieName;
movie.MovieBio = viewModel.MovieBio;
movie.MoviePosterUrl = viewModel.MoviePosterUrl;
```

Towards the reference navigation key which is present in the join table/navigational table like this

```
 cinemaShowtime.CinemaInstance = cinema;
 cinemaShowtime.MoviesInstance = movie;
```

Also the system was asking to make the composite key nullable which is present in Movie Table table like this

```
 public int? IndustryId { get; set; }
```

It should be noted that I am making many-to-many relationship same thing would happen for cinema table