# SaveChanges error when adding a person in Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I've got the following piece of code:

```cs
var SelectAll = eF.People.ToList();

People P1 = new People();
P1.PersonID = 4;
P1.Name = "Iman";
P1.Family = "Rajabi";
P1.Age = 40;

eF.People.Add(P1);
eF.SaveChanges();
```

I get the following error when adding a person:

[image: DbUpdateException]

Comment: Do you have primary key set up? Please share your entity's structure.

Comment: Here is the answer for your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322894/because-it-has-a-definingquery-and-no-insertfunction-element-exists-in-the-mo#answers-header

Comment: You need to define the PK via Fluent api

Comment: Navigate to this link, I think this will solve your error.
[How to avoid System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762923/how-to-avoid-system-data-entity-infrastructure-dbupdateexception/20765016)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the field PersonID is possibly a primary key. Often in SQL server in addition to this, a primary key is often an identity column, meaning that SQL Server typically manages these values for you. If this is the case, you should not set the PersonID value. In addition, you may need to annotate the PersonId column in your model.

For some examples have a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: I make the main key again, this is the same PersonID error